# "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" while using bcrypt.hashpw()

Tags: python-3.x

SCREENSHOT[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNlVR.png)

I have tried everything. but I was unable to remove the error. even tried to forcefully remove 'encoding='utf-8'' but was unsuccessful

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include your code and the full error(s) in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode `word` into bytes with `utf-8` encoding before passing it to `bcrypt.hashpw`.

```
cryptWord = bcrypt.hashpw(word.encode('utf-8'), salt)
```